# Read iso_3166_2.js using rjson package in R

Tags: r, json

I need to read `js` in R to download `iso_3166_2` data. How I can use `rjson` to read?

```
library("rjson")
json_file <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oodavid/iso-3166-2/master/iso_3166_2.js"
lines <- readLines(json_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages like `rjson` and `jsonlite` expect to read properly formatted JSON data, not arbitrary javascript files. You can verify something is in JSON format with a [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/). In this you are lucky that it's pretty *close* to a proper JSON file, you just need to clean a few things up. you just need to clean up the first and last lines

```
json_file <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oodavid/iso-3166-2/master/iso_3166_2.js"
lines <- readLines(json_file)
lines[1] <- gsub(".*(?={)", "", lines[1], perl=TRUE)
lines[length(lines)] <- gsub(";.*$", "", lines[length(lines)], perl=TRUE)
mydata <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste(lines, collapse="\n"))
```

Here I used `jsonlite` rather than `rjson` because it more easily allows vectors for input and doesn't seem to get tripped up on quote encoding.